# How to sort array of objects based on a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a `string` and `array` like this:

```
const speech = 'marcllh 4th reg gh 4th ethth';

const similarityArray = [

  { split: '4th reg' },
  { split: 'reg gh' },
  { split: 'ethth' },
  { split: 'marcllh' },
  { split: '4th reg gh' },
  { split: '4th ethth' },

];
```

I want to sort the `array` based on the `string` from start to end.

So the desired result would be this array:

```
{ split: 'marcllh' },
{ split: '4th reg' },
{ split: '4th reg gh' }, // this is the continued of the previous one
{ split: 'reg gh' },
{ split: '4th ethth' }
{ split: 'ethth' },
```

Note that if a longer version of spited text exist it should come next as you see in the commented element.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Sort by `.indexOf()` + `.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your reference.

```js
const string = 'marcllh 4th reg gh 4th ethth';

const array = [
 
{ split: '4th reg gh' },
{ split: '4th reg' },
{ split: 'reg gh' },
{ split: 'ethth' },
{ split: 'marcllh' },
{ split: '4th ethth' }

];

array.sort((a,b) => {
  var ia = string.indexOf(a['split']);
  var ib = string.indexOf(b['split']);
  var result = ia - ib;
  if(result == 0){
     result = a['split'].length - b['split'].length;
  }
  return result;
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Why does this no-effort question deserve an answer?

Comment: Don't get it.  Clearly a homework exercise that should not have gotten a direct answer, IMHO because we promote graduates that know nothing.  Just my $0.02 as a senior dev that will have to deal with potential good for nothing's in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework to me, so I won't give you the actual complete code for this.

The algorithm would be to:

1. Iterate through the array.
2. Determine the starting index of each of the elements in the string.
3. Sort the array based on the index values, in ascending order.
4. If there are two indexes with the same value, disambiguate by putting the shortest array element first.
5. End.

Good luck!